# GeneralHtmlSupport allowed elements not working as expected in inline editor on CkEditor 5

Tags: javascript, regex, ckeditor, ckeditor5, fckeditor

I have a custom build with both CkEditor Classic and Inline, using GHS to filter some tags on the classic editor works as expected but on the inline editor tags like `<a>` (and maybe some other ones too) are pasted in and not filtered

The HTML support config is:

```
var htmlSupport = {
            allow: [{
                name: /^(br|em|i|small|sup|sub|u)$/,
                classes: false,
                styles: false
            }]
            disallow: [{
                name: /[\s\S]+/,    // For every HTML feature,
                attributes: {
                    key: /^contenteditable$/
                }
            }]      
};
```

I have tried to set individual tags on allow rather than a regex and to set the tag on the disallow list too

Comment: I am having the same issue. Nothing I do gets the editor to allow html to be parsed in. Even the following the documentation: 
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/html/general-html-support.html#demo

Answer (score 0):

you can try using superbuild package it contains all the necessary packages required for that.

```
 <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/41.2.1/super-build/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

use below toolbar config

toolbar: {
items: [
'sourceEditing'
],
shouldNotGroupWhenFull: true
},
sourceEditing: {
allowCollaborationFeatures: true
},